# How to use a class category Objective C in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

I have a class category wrote in Objective C. I need use this in Swift. But I don't know how to declare this to call.

```
      var vcfPart: NSDictionary = [kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey:"video/quicktime;\r\n\tx-unix-mode=0644;\r\n\tname=\"video.mp4\"", kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey:"attachment;\r\n\tfilename=\"video.mp4\"", kSKPSMTPPartContentDispositionKey: self.rep ,kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey:"base64", kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey: "8bit"]
```

data is of type NSData. I need encode this with NSData+Base64Additions https://github.com/kailoa/iphone-smtp/blob/master/Classes/NSData%2BBase64Additions.m

in objective c call:

```
 NSDictionary * vcfPart3 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"video/quicktime;\r\n\tx-unix-mode=0644;\r\n\tname=\"video.mp4\"",kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,
                           @"attachment;\r\n\tfilename=\"video.mp4\"",kSKPSMTPPartContentDispositionKey, [data encodeWrappedBase64ForData], kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey, @"base64", kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey, nil];
```

I don't know how to declare this in Swift with an extension..

How can use this in Swift?

Thanks!

Comment: "in objective c call:" It is also not possible to declare an instance variable in a category in Objective-C. Plus this code cannot be an instance variable declaration in Objective-C, because they cannot have initializers. So it is very unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Extensions can't contain stored properties, as I'm sure the compiler has already informed you. If this is actually a constant, express it as a [computed property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-XID_374) and you'll be fine.

In other words, this is illegal in an extension:

```
let i = 4
```

But this is legal:

```
var i : Int {
    return 4
}
```

Comment: I don't understand you, an example?

Comment: but my doubt is how to call or return my data with - (NSString *)encodeWrappedBase64ForData?

Comment: It's funny but I don't see anything about that in your question. You asked (as far as I can tell) how to declare a variable in an extension. I showed you how. The phrase `- (NSString *)encodeWrappedBase64ForData` doesn't appear anywhere in your question. Are you now asking a different question? If so, ask a different question.